# MongoDB- huge data size?

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB, i have a collection which has the following fields:

```
> db.TestTable.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("527c48e99000cf10bc2a1d82"),
        "ID" : "16587",
        "Name" : "N15247",
        "Serial1" : "11",
        "Serial2" : "727",
        "DateTime" : ISODate("1998-12-15T18:30:00Z"),
        "CompID" : "ID465",
        "CompName" : "F1460"
}
```

I have inserted around 300,000,000 documents into the collection using a c# driver using BsonDocument. The size of the collection is:

```
> db.TestTable.stats()
{
        "ns" : "FeatureParser.LogsTable",
        "count" : 300000000,
        "size" : 62399477600,
        "avgObjSize" : 207.99825866666666,
        "storageSize" : 68783787568,
        "numExtents" : 54,
        "nindexes" : 2,
        "lastExtentSize" : 2146426864,
        "paddingFactor" : 1,
        "systemFlags" : 1,
        "userFlags" : 0,
        "totalIndexSize" : 14878186064,
        "indexSizes" : {
                "_id_" : 9746789472,
                "dateTime_1" : 5131396592
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Does MongoDB take so much space for the documents inserteD? Is there anyway the size of the DB can be reduced?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### To be expected

It's not clear in what way the stored size is considered huge - what size is to be expected?

> I have inserted around [300M] documents

Each rows is approximately 200 bytes:

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("527c48e99000cf10bc2a1d82"),"ID" : "16587","Name" : "N15247","Serial1" : "11","Serial2" : "727","DateTime" : ISODate("1998-12-15T18:30:00Z"),"CompID" : "ID465","CompName" : "F1460"}
^199 chars
```

Which is reported/confirmed as:

> "avgObjSize" : 207.99825866666666 [bytes]

with a total data size of:

> "size" : 62399477600 [bytes]

Therefore:

```
    300, 000, 000 rows x
              200 bytes per row
60, 000, 000, 000 bytes
```

Which simply confirms that the estimate of the data inserted, is very close to the size of the data in the collection (62GiB v 60GiB).

The actual storage size is `68, 783, 787, 568` (68GiB)  which is also pretty close to the data size, the difference being overhead for indexes and pre-allocation of storage space.

As such the results observed are easily to be expected. If the above isn't what's meant - please clarify by editing the question.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right and the calculation/estimation is more or less correct. The surprise might be, that pure, naked data only takes ~40 bytes, but consumes 200 bytes. And taking the string-length of the JSON could be a value to calculate with, but e.g. `ObjectId("527c48e99000cf10bc2a1d82")` takes only 12 bytes binary.

Comment: It's meant very much as a dumb/finger-in-the air estimate, that anyone can do. I'm aware for example that taking the length of a json representation as bytes is pretty weak =) just meant as a means to verify the average row and storage size is about right.

Comment: Didn't want to criticize your answer. I agree with it. Just wanted to say that MongoDB seems to be quite greedy with space storing simple objects.

Comment: I understood your original meaning =)

Answer (score 3):

From http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/

> **Preallocated data files.**
>   In the data directory, MongoDB preallocates
>   data files to a particular size, in part to prevent file system
>   fragmentation. MongoDB names the first data file .0, the
>   next .1, etc. **The first file mongod allocates is 64
>   megabytes, the next 128 megabytes, and so on, up to 2 gigabytes, at
>   which point all subsequent files are 2 gigabytes.** The data files
>   include files with allocated space but that hold no data. mongod may
>   allocate a 1 gigabyte data file that may be 90% empty. For most larger
>   databases, unused allocated space is small compared to the database.

Comment: At 300m rows preallocation shouldn't be the effect, especially since it is sitting at around 58 GB, which means 2gb allocation is only effecting the last 2gb of that 58gb, also providing more than a quote to explain your logic helps

Answer (score 1):

People already suggested the reason why collection is so big, so instead of rephrasing their words, I would address the second question. How to decrease the size of the collection.

There is one nice way to reduce the size of your collection.

Because mongodb stores keys for every document, you can substantially reduce the size of the collection by shortening the names. This way you will have collection with documents like this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("527c48e99000cf10bc2a1d82"),
        "ID" : "16587",
        "n" : "N15247",
        "s" : "11",
        "c" : "727",
        "d" : ISODate("1998-12-15T18:30:00Z"),
        "c" : "ID465",
        "f" : "F1460"
}
```

and on your application layer you can create a mapping from these cryptic names to normal names.

Comment: I would bet £100 his field names are not his problem though, and prolly won't do much

Comment: I would bet 100$ that I was not telling that this is the root of problems. I just suggested a way to reduce the size of the collection.

Comment: @Sammaye actually it would - removing ~30 bytes from each record would reduce the collection size by 9GiB. (+1 as it's a useful technique/information).

Comment: @Sammaye his document weights 144 bytes, mine is 104. So this increase in 28%. If also to convert some of the strings which looks like ints to integers, this can save additional few bytes. So it might be a good way of reducing the size.

Comment: Actually it won't, we found this out in another question, the string representation seems to use less, forgot why

Comment: @AD7six if 9GB out of 58GB is worth it, I guess it is opinionated, actually 7GB due to allocation

Comment: That I don't know =) since it's not clear in what way inserting a significant amount of data into a database being stored as a significant (and similar/equivalent) amount of storage space is unexpected.

Comment: @Sammaye most probably that finding was wrong. Because string representation will be less only if your size of the string is less then 4 chars. (because int is 4 bytes and char is 1 byte). So if you will do: db.a.insert({a : '11111'}); db.b.insert({a : 11111}); and then compare db.a.stats().size with db.b.stats().size, you will see that string is bigger.

Comment: @AD7six Indeed though to look at it again maybe 7GB is worth it over the ambiguity of the names in things like MR etc

Comment: No I remember now it was 4bytes and under that's why

Comment: It's a pitty that MongoDB doesn't use a simple map for fieldnames and store the documents internally w/o long fieldnames. Obviously this would cost additional processing and buffering server-side... Reminds me of very early days of computing :-)

Comment: @hgoebl MongoDB will get field compression in the next 2 versions hopefully which will mean that field names are now a 10th of the document size, edit: more like a fraction but you know